# Definite Integration, keep getting wrong answer.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Correct to 4 significant figures
>   $$\int_{1}^{2}{\csc^24tdt}$$

Done this multiple times now and can't seem to get the answer at the back of the book.
Here's my attempt:
$$\int_{1}^{2}{\csc^24tdt}$$
$$-\dfrac{1}{4}\left[\cot 4(2)-\cot 4(1)\right]_{1}^{2}$$
$$-\dfrac{1}{4}\left[\frac{1}{\tan 8}-\frac{1}{\tan4}\right]$$
$$-\dfrac{1}{4}\left[-0.1471-0.8637\right]$$
$$-\dfrac{1}{4}\left[-1.0108\right]$$
$$0.2527$$

Back of the book has a similar answer which is $0.2572$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: First of all, are you sure this can be integrated over that range? What happens when $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: No idea, I'm just doing questions from the book, (John Bird, Engineering Mathematics)

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cosec%5E2%284x%29+dx+from+1+to+2

https://www.symbolab.com/solver/calculus-calculator/%5Cint_%7B1%7D%5E%7B2%7D%20csc%5E%7B2%7D%5Cleft(4x%5Cright)dx/?origin=enterkey

The area must be infinite, and not the answer you've received, due to the presence of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ between 1 and 2, where the curve tends towards infinity.

Comment: Apologies, I get what you mean now @Deepak I wonder how I was able to receive an answer even though the area must is infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is wrong. Plain and simple. They transposed the last two digits, which is a simple typo. Originally, I was going to write the following, and I include it here for numerical reference.

You need to do all the rounding right at the end. Since we have calculators today, which usually carry 12-16 digits of precision, round-off error is the least of our worries. If you carry out the calculations without intermediate rounding, you get an answer of: $0.2527$.

As an aside, you cannot evaluate the integral directly, since it passes through a discontinuity at $\frac{\pi}{2}$, as shown below:

[image: discontinuity marked in dashed red line]

Answer (score 1):

The antiderivative is perfectly correct $$\int{\csc^2(4t)\,dt}=-\frac{1}{4} \cot (4 t)$$ but, as already said in comments and answers, $\cot (4 t)$ shows a discontinuity at $t=\frac \pi 2$ and this value is just between the bounds. So, let us consider $$I=\int_1^{\frac \pi 2-\epsilon}{\csc^2(4t)\,dt}=\frac{1}{4} (\cot (4 \epsilon )+\cot (4))$$ $$J=\int_{\frac \pi 2+\epsilon}^2{\csc^2(4t)\,dt}=\frac{1}{4} (\cot (4 \epsilon )-\cot (8))$$ $$I+J=\frac{1}{2} \cot (4 \epsilon )+\frac{1}{4}\csc (8)$$ The last term $\frac{1}{4}\csc (8)\approx 0.252689$ corresponds to the answer of the book but the problem is really with the first terms $\frac{1}{2} \cot (4 \epsilon )$. Using Taylor series built at $\epsilon=0$, $$\frac{1}{2} \cot (4 \epsilon )=\frac{1}{8 \epsilon }-\frac{2 \epsilon }{3}+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$ which shows the problem perfectly illustrated by FundThmCalculus's answer.